# django - DecimalField act as float field with default value 0.00?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

i have code below

```
CartModel

total = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
```

for this total, i checked in admin its value is 0.0 and **type(total)** showing as **Float** instead of  **Decimal**
and if assign value Decimal('13.00') it show error like

`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'float' and 'decimal.Decimal'`

why default=0.00 consider as float and giving this error?

i am debugging below code

```
Media model
    price = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)


@receiver(post_save, sender=CartEntry)
def update_media_cart_on_create(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    line_cost = instance.media.price
    instance.cart.total += line_cost
    instance.cart.count += 1
    instance.cart.updated = timezone.now()
    instance.cart.save()
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think `type(total)` return `float`, Could you show how di you tested the type?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu line number 4 i put break point and check their values, at that time total = 0.0 and line_cost= Decimal('13.00')

Comment: Is `line_cost` a `float` data? How does your media model/variable look like?

Comment: no, its decimal filed, i added debugging photo, tried everything i think this is django bug or mine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're providing a `float` as the default value. Instead, provide a Decimal default: `Decimal('0.00')`.

If you haven't already, you'll need to `from decimal import Decimal`.

Comment: thx its worked but makemigrations wont detect any changes